# Is it possible to check if a Freeform Pro form has any kind of error?

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, validation

In my template I have a Freeform Pro composer form with inline error handling turned on. I know that I can check if a certain field has an error by going:

```
{if freeform:error:{composer:field_name}}
```

And I can check for general errors with:

```
{if freeform:general_errors}
```

But, is there a way to check if the (whole) form had any kind of error? Something like:

```
{if freeform:has_errors} (doesn't work)
```

I want to output a general error message in addition to the field and general errors. The fields are dynamic, so checking every one of them is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by using the `inline_error_return=""` parameter:
http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#inline_error_return

For example, you could craft a special URL when inline errors are encountered, eg:

```
return="template_group/template/errors_found"
```

Then, in your template, use a simple conditional to display your "has errors" message:

```
{if segment_3 == "errors_found"}Errors were found in your form{/if}
```

Comment: Yes, that could work, didn't think of using inline_error_return to the same page.